# Sequences that commute with gcd

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

> Which sequences of integers $P_n$ satisfy
>   $\gcd(P_m,P_n) = P_{\gcd(m,n)}$ ?

This is true for the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Divisibility_properties).

More generally,

> Which sequences of integer polynomials 
>   satisfy
>   $\gcd(P_m(x),P_n(x)) = P_{\gcd(m,n)}(x)$ ?

(I think this is true for the [Fibonacci polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials).)

Comment: Motivated by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387994/prove-the-following-algebra-of-polynomials.

Comment: $P_n(x)=x^n-1\,$ for one example.

Comment: They are called [strong divisibility sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence). Searching on that will locate much literature.

Comment: @divx Yes, e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1867085/242) where I give the addition law for $\,f_n = (x^n-y^n)/(x-y).\,$  I mention some (strong)  divisibility sequences in passing in [various answers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+%22divisibility+sequence%22)

Comment: @BillDubuque, ah, I didn't know the term "strong divisibility sequence". Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269874/what-is-the-significance-of-a-divisibility-sequence.

Comment: @lhf But I mentioned it last year in the [prior-linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1867085/242) whose comments you participated in! $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I go back to old posts of mine, and don't even understand *them*!

Comment: @lhf what is an application of this identity?

Comment: @EyesOnBud See e.g. the linked "various answers" above.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145404/the-gcd-operator-commutes-with-functions-defined-by-linear-recurrence-relatio.