# If we have $\gcd(a_n,a_m)=a_{\gcd(n,m)}$ for each pair then $a_1,a_2,...$ is Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

It is well known that for each pair $f_n,f_m$ in Fibonacci sequence we have
$$\gcd(f_n,f_m)=f_{\gcd(n,m)}$$

What about the other way? If we have $\gcd(a_n,a_m)=a_{\gcd(n,m)}$ for each pair in nonconstant sequence $a_1,a_2,...$ of natural nubers, then it is Fibonacci sequence?

---

For start I was thinking only about a sequence of form $a_{n+1} = \alpha a_n+ \beta  a_{n-1}$ and all I can find is that $a_1=a_2$ and that $a_1\mid a_n$ for each $n$. Also $a_2\mid a_3$.

Comment: $\gcd(2^n-1, 2^m-1) = 2^{\gcd(n,m)}-1$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388228/sequences-that-commute-with-gcd and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence

Comment: Great! Thanks....

Comment: How about these : $a_n=n$, $a_n=1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $\gcd(x_n,x_m)=x_{\gcd(n,m)}$ is called a [strong divisibility sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence).

A simple example of a strong divisibility sequence that is not the Fibonacci sequence is $x_n = a^n-1$, where $a \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1.

Comment: Also, note that these sequences are of the form specified by OP: since they are a linear combination of two exponentials $r\cdot a^n+s\cdot 1^n$ (where $r=1, s=-1$) then they satisfy a linear recurrence whose characteristic polynomial has roots $a, 1$; in other words, whose characteristic equation is $(x-a)(x-1) = x^2-(a+1)+a=0$, or (pulling it back to the recurrence) $x_n = (a+1)x_{n-1}-ax_{n-2}$ with appropriate initial conditions ($x_0=0, x_1=a-1$).

Comment: Look in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org) for interesting examples of elliptic divisibility sequences.